# Vapor join and alsoDecode produces lots of nested tuples

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

According to answer from question: [vapor - Obtaining data from mysql using alsodecode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484138/vapor-obtaining-data-from-mysql-using-alsodecode) I was able to reproduce this for my model with multiple joins.

This resulted with multiple nested tuples which I have to access to get joined values. Is it possible to make other type of join or flatten this tuple structure to one level?

```
struct MyTuple: Encodable, Content {
    let title: String
    let publicationDate: Date
    let authorID: Author.ID
    let authorName: String
    let categoryID: Category.ID
    let categoryName: String
    let language: String
}

struct MyContext: Encodable {
    let title: String
    let books: [MyTuple]
}

func getBooks(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[MyTuple]> {
    return Book.query(on: req)
        .join(\Category.id, to: \Book.categoryID)
        .join(\Language.id, to: \Book.languageID)
        .join(\ProgrammingLanguage.id, to: \Book.programmingLanguageID)
        .join(\Author.id, to: \Book.authorID)
        .alsoDecode(Category.self)
        .alsoDecode(Language.self)
        .alsoDecode(ProgrammingLanguage.self)
        .alsoDecode(Author.self)
        .sort(\Book.publicationDate, .descending).all().flatMap(to: [MyTuple].self) { tuples in
            print(tuples)
            var tempTuples: [MyTuple] = []
            for tuple in tuples {
                tempTuples.append(try MyTuple(
                        title: tuple.0.0.0.0.title,
                        publicationDate: tuple.0.0.0.0.publicationDate,
                        authorID: tuple.1.requireID(),
                        authorName: "\(tuple.1.name) \(tuple.1.surname)",
                        categoryID: tuple.0.0.0.1.requireID(),
                        categoryName: tuple.0.0.0.1.name, language: tuple.0.0.1.code ) )
            }

            return Future.map(on: req) {
                tempTuples
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with raw query, something like this

```swift
func getBooks(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[MyTuple]> {
    let rawSQL = """
    SELECT
        Book.title,
        Book.publicationDate,
        Book.authorID,
        concat(Author.name, " ", Author.surname) as authorName,
        Book.categoryID,
        Category.name as categoryName,
        Language.code as language
    FROM Book
    JOIN LEFT Category ON Category.id = Book.categoryID
    JOIN LEFT Language ON Language.id = Book.languageID
    JOIN LEFT ProgrammingLanguage ON ProgrammingLanguage.id = Book.programmingLanguageID
    JOIN LEFT Author ON Author.id = Book.authorID
    ORDER BY Book.publicationDate DESC
"""
    return req.requestPooledConnection(to: .mysql).flatMap { conn in
        return conn.raw(rawSQL).all(decoding: MyTuple.self).always {
            try? req.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .mysql)
        }
    }
}
```

or with raw query using SwifQL library

```swift
func getBooks(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[MyTuple]> {
    return SwifQL
            .select(\Book.title,
                    \Book.publicationDate,
                    \Book.authorID,
                    Fn.concat(\Author.name, " ", \Author.surname) => "authorName",
                    \Book.categoryID,
                    \Category.name => categoryName,
                    \Language.code => language)
            .from(Book.table)
            .join(.left, Category.table, on: \Category.id == \Book.categoryID)
            .join(.left, Language.table, on: \ Language.id == \Book.languageID)
            .join(.left, ProgrammingLanguage.table, on: \ ProgrammingLanguage.id == \Book.programmingLanguageID)
            .join(.left, Author.table, on: \ Author.id == \Book. Book.authorID)
            .orderBy(.desc(\Book.publicationDate))
            .execute(on: req, as: .mysql)
            .all(decoding: MyTuple.self)
}
```

the same as above but with select builder

```swift
func getBooks(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[MyTuple]> {
    let query = SwifQLSelectBuilder()
    query.select(\Book.title)
    query.select(\Book.publicationDate)
    query.select(\Book.authorID)
    query.select(Fn.concat(\Author.name, " ", \Author.surname) => "authorName")
    query.select(\Book.categoryID,
    query.select(\Category.name => categoryName)
    query.select(\Language.code => language)
    query.from(Book.table)
    query.join(.left, Category.table, on: \Category.id == \Book.categoryID)
    query.join(.left, Language.table, on: \Language.id == \Book.languageID)
    query.join(.left, ProgrammingLanguage.table, on: \ProgrammingLanguage.id == \Book.programmingLanguageID)
    query.join(.left, Author.table, on: \Author.id == \Book. Book.authorID)
    query.orderBy(.desc(\Book.publicationDate))
    return query.build()
                .execute(on: req, as: .mysql)
                .all(decoding: MyTuple.self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @imike. Although I know SQL quite well I feel that second solution is more Swifty way to do it in vapor?

Comment: Yeah sure second solution is more Swifty cause it support refactoring, so if you change some models you will not forget to change your queries.

Comment: that's great cause to use second version. thank you again for help ... my API gets better with your answers

Comment: I got compiler error with above query: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" any way to fix it?

Comment: If the problem is in long `select` expression then you could split it using `SwifQLSelectBuilder()` check my updated answer. But honestly I never faced with this kind of error with SwifQL. I have two ideas: either there is just an error in the code above somewhere, so you could find the problem by commenting all lines and uncommenting them line by line, or it is also may be the bug in Xcode 11.2+. I'm still on 11.1 cause it works pretty well.

Comment: error appeared on last line of function  `.all(decoding: MyTuple.self)`, tried `SwiQLSelectBuilder` and it works. thank you